# I want to save the date and time like 2019-05-27 10:04:35 in neo4j

Tags: node.js, spring-data-neo4j

I want to save the current date time in neo4j .

while want to save the message  node

```
private Long messageId;
private User toUser;
private User fromUser;
private String message;
private String creationTime;

messege.setSender(
  userRepository.getUserbyId( 
    messageRequestResponse.getFromUser().getId()));

messege.setReciever(
  userRepository.getUserbyId(
    messageRequestResponse.getToUser().getId()));

messege.setMessege(messageRequestResponse.getMessage());

chatMessegeRepository.save(messege);
```

Please help.

Comment: are you using spring or node.js if you are using spring then you can use default auditing feature to save current date and time in neo4j

Comment: Thanks Vipul . I solved it by using default auditing feature.

Comment: cool dude @rakesh